# Solving $yy''+(y')^2- \frac{2yy'}x + \frac{y^3}{x^3}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$yy''+(y')^2- \frac{2yy'}x + \frac{y^3}{x^3}=0$$

I have a problem with this differential equation. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What problem do you have?  Finding properties of the solution?  Numerical computation?  [Since most nonlinear DEs do not have closed form solution, it would seem unlikely that this one does.]

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=y^2$, then
$$u'=2yy'$$
$$\frac{1}{2}u''=yy''+(y')^2$$

So, the equation reduces to
$$\frac{1}{2}u''-\frac{1}{x}u'=-\frac{u^{3\over 2}}{x^3}$$

This is an Emden-Fowler equation, for which there is literature on exact solutions (under some specific conditions) and approximation schemes.